# Check size(variable) of all string in List using Java Stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream

I have a list of strings (given below), each string required to be in a specific size(Variable).

for e.g.

```
{"abc","xyz","def"}
```

this list elements has a fixed size of 3 and i would like to check if this size is not exceed to X=3 or 4.

Requirement is to return a boolean if that size exceed or lower the size. I refereed Java Stream docs couldn't find any relevant information.
Does Java Stream API is useful to solve this or should i solve it in classical way.

Comment: do you want to check if each item in the list if of given size (n)??

Comment: @AnimeshSahu these returns size of list not of it's individual Item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [the `allMatch` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) like this:

```
int correctSize = 3;
List<String> myStrings = List.of("abc", "xyz", "def");
boolean allAreCorrectSize = myStrings.stream()
    .allMatch(s -> s.length() == correctSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here both implementation, both can be used

1. Using Stream API

```java
public static boolean isValidUsingStreamAPI(List<String> list){
        int correctSize=3;
        return list.stream().allMatch(f->f.length()==correctSize);
}
```

2. Classic Way

```java
public static boolean isValidClassic(List<String> list){
        int correctSize=3;
        for(String s:list){
            if(s.length()!=correctSize)return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```